# get_terms() order by term_meta

Tags: terms, term-meta

I'm doing a `get_terms()` query that I'm trying to order by a custom term meta. The custom term meta key is `'order'` which as a numeric value (between 1 and 10). I have tried the following, but the order doesn't seem to follow the meta value - any pointers is appreciated.

```
$type_terms = get_terms( 'type', array(
    'hide_empty' => false,
    array(
        'key' => 'order',
    ),
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
) );
```

Comment: Replace the `array('key' => 'order',),` with `'meta_key' => 'order',`

Comment: Thanks - this seems to work. Please put as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I've done that, which you already know. I edited the answer so that it would be more clarified to other users. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the order doesn't seem to follow the meta value

Yes, and it's because you set the meta key like this: (which doesn't actually set the meta key)

```
array(
  'key' => 'order',
),
```

The proper way is by using the `meta_key` parameter:

```
'meta_key' => 'order'
```

So the full code would be:

```
$type_terms = get_terms( 'type', array(
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'meta_key' => 'order',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
) );
```

For more information, please refer to [`WP_Term_Query::__construct()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/#parameters), which is used by the [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/#parameters) function.